# How to create an instance of a class in Java BlueJ?

Tags: java, class, instance, bluej

I've been told to create an instance of this class and to call drawGalaxy(). When I try compile and calling it, it says it can not find method "drawGalaxy". Any help? :/

```
 public class GalaxyQuest
        {
            private Galaxy galaxy;

            /**
             * Creates a new instance of Galaxy Quest.
             */
            public GalaxyQuest() 
            {   
                initialiseGalaxy("GalaxyData.txt");
            }

            /**
             * Draws the galaxy to the console.
             */
            public void drawGalaxy()
            {
                galaxy.drawGalaxy();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a method called `drawGalaxy` in the class `Galaxy`?

Comment: have u added an import statement , if you have the Galaxy in some other package and as @Christian said check for the method

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create an instance of your Class in Java:

```
GalaxyQuest g = new GalaxyQuest();
```

You can then call public methods like this:

```
g.drawGalaxy();
```

About your error, if it can't find a drawGalaxy() method in an instance of the class Galaxy, it means one of two things:

1. The method does not exist. In this case, you should define it.
2. The method is not public, ie, only accessible from within Galaxy. Read up on [access specifiers](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/introduction-to-java-access-modifiers) & declare the method to be public.

You can read more about creating Java objects [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).